# Saving LatLng and List<Address> in SharedPreference

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, geolocation, sharedpreferences

Is it possible to save LatLng and List in SharedPreference? From another activity i need to retrieve this values. What will be the easiest way to achieve this? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I use for storing complex objects (other than String, Int, etc) in shared preferences. It also works with Lists. You will need to add gson to your project (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Hope this helps!

```
public <T> void putComplex(String key, T value){
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create();
    String data = gson.toJson(value);
    Editor ed = getSettings(context).edit();
    ed.putString(key, data);
    ed.commit();
}


public <T> T getComplex(String key, Class<T> type){
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create();
    String data = getSettings(context).getString(key, null);
    if (data==null){
        return null;
    }
    return gson.fromJson(data, type);
}

protected static SharedPreferences getSettings(Context context){
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(AppConfig.APP_ID, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return settings;
}   


public static Address getAddress(Context context){
    return getComplex(SP_ADDRESS, Address.class);
}

public static void setAddress(Context context, Address address){
    putComplex(SP_ADDRESS, address);
}
```